# CMake - Optionally including a static library if compiled in a subproject

Tags: c++, c, cmake

We have a project where in based on some settings, we may or may not compile a static library in our project. In case we don't build it we would be using a dummy implementation that is wrapped inside the DUMMY_LIB_IMPL macro. To be more clear;

```
{ROOT_DIR}/ 
  CMakeLists.txt
  |
  |_ P1/CMakeLists.txt --> The cmake file which has the below snippet
  |_ P2/CMakeLists.txt --> May/MayNot compile "lib_that_may_be_compiled_by_us"
```

So this is part of what we ended up with in the P1/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_library(OPTIONAL_LIB lib_that_may_be_compiled_by_us)
if(OPTIONAL_LIB)
    target_link_libraries(p1 lib_that_may_be_compiled_by_us)
    message("Found library at" ${OPTIONAL_LIB})
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DDUMMY_LIB_IMPL")
    message("Could not find client library enabling MACRO DUMMY_LIB_IMPL")
endif()
```

Unfortunately, find_lib(...) here does not seem to be able to find the library. Tried adding the path where we build it but doesnt help.

Is there an alternate way to achieve something similar? Whats wrong with the current snippet above?

Comment: Okay.. so we found one possible solution. In P2/CMakeLists.txt we set a variable like this "set(OPTIONAL_LIB_AVAILABLE ON PARENT_SCOPE)"

We use this in P1/CMakeLists.txt to make a decision like (if (OPTIONAL_LIB_AVAILABLE))

Comment: "Whats wrong with the current snippet above?" - `find_library` isn't applicable for the libraries built in the **project itself**. This is because the command searched the library file at **configuration** stage, but that file is created only during the *build*. Common options, like described in your comment, are perfectly fit for conditional configuration. Also, instead of checking the option, you may check existence of the library **target**: `if(TARGET lib_that_may_be_compiled_by_us)`.